# How to find and set-location to Folder?

Tags: powershell

How to find the folder and change the current folder to one of the found ones?

Something like:

```
ls C:\Users "My folder" -recurse
```

Then cd "My folder" from search list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your Powershell version:

```
gci C:\Users "My folder" -Rec -EA 0|? {$_.PSIsContainer}|Get-Random|sl
```

or

```
gci C:\Users "My folder" -Rec -Dir -EA 0|Get-Random|sl
```

or

```
gci C:\Users "My folder" -Rec -Dir -EA 0|select -last 1 |sl
```

- Intentionally using PS aliases
- `-EA 0`  is an abbrev for `-ErrorAction silently continue`

Comment: `ls "" "New Folder" -Rec | select -last 1| sl` works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$dirs = ls C:\Users "My folder" -Directory -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
cd $dirs[0]
```

Comment: $dirs list is initialized, folder found but at `cd $dirs[0]` im getting exception: object type System.IO.DirectoryInfo cannot be indexed.
строка:1 знак:10
+ cd $dirs[ <<<< 0]
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (0:Int32) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotIndex

Comment: Are you calling the code as above, or is $dirs being populated some other way?

Comment: `$dirs = ls C:\Users "My folder" -Recurse` Then i checking with `$dir` and it shows me folder in list

Comment: Parameter **-Directory** cause to Exception: Cannot resolve parameter at Get-ChildItem

Comment: See above, I think you can just ignore directories which may be too long.